# Is there a particular reason to name the main character 'Michael Faraday' after the scientist?

Tags: character, arlington-road

Is there a particular reason to name the main character 'Michael Faraday', apparently after the scientist?

I couldn't find anything in history that would appear relevant to the plotline.

Comment: also, how do you think the movie would have turned out had the FBI agent and faraday's girlfriend had better instincts and situational awareness ? unless faraday had raised false alarms in the past, practically everyone he knew was imbicilic